# UI not updating even with dispatch_get_main_queue()

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, dispatch-async

I understand that all updates to the UI need to happen on the main thread.  I have code that makes an Alamofire request and updates the user with the progress made as it parses each item from the JSON response.  I have placed `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){}` around the line that sets the text of a `UILabel`, and yet the label does not update.  My `for` loop prints to the logs “We’re on item 0”, “We’re on item 1”, etc. and the whole time my label text never shows up.   If I update the label after my `getPhotoCollection()` function is over,  the label text displays as expected — so there’s nothing wrong with my UILabel itself.

I have found countless Stack Overflow posts saying that if you want to update the UI from code that isn’t on the main thread, simply wrap it in `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){}`. So why is that not working?

Here is my code.  I have left some irrelevant parts in it in case they are part of why this issue is occurring.

```
func getPhotoCollection(urlString: String, finished: (success: Bool, numResults: Int) -> Void) {
    Alamofire.request(.GET, urlString, parameters: nil, encoding: .JSON)
        .validate()
        .responseJSON { (response) -> Void in
            guard response.result.isSuccess else {
                finished(success: false, numResults: 0)
                return
             }  
            let json = response.result.value!
            if let items = json["items"] as? NSArray {
                 let numResults = items.count
                 if numResults > 0 {    
                     self.photoArray.removeAll()
                     var itemNum = 0
                     for item in items {
                         var photo: UIImage!                        
                         let jsonItem = JSON(item)
                         let photoURLString = jsonItem["url"].stringValue
                         let url = NSURL(string: photoURLString)
                         print("We're on item \(itemNum)")
                         if let imageData = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!) {
                             dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                                 self.progressLabel.text = String(itemNum + 1) + " photos found"
                             }
                             photo = UIImage(data: data)
                             self.photoArray.append(photo)
                             itemNum++
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    finished(success: true, numResults: numResults)
                    return
                }
            }       
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you check to make sure that the if condition in `if let imageData = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!)` evaluates to true? Is the URL valid and do you get data for the contents of the URL?

Comment: Yes.  Not only is it true, but the for loop does 5 iterations, each of which successfully appends a photo to my `photoArray`.

Comment: Are you by any chance able to share the full project (or a demo project showing the issue) so that I can run it to see what might be going on?

Comment: The problem is that Alamofire callbacks are already called on the main thread, therefore calling `let imageData = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!)` will block the main thread. You need to call that on some background queue instead.

Comment: `NSData(contentsOfURL:)` will block the main thread until the download is complete. That will cause long "pregnant pauses" as each image is downloaded, but it should still work eventually (unless your app gets terminate for being unresponsive). Clay, what happens if you let your program run for several minutes?

Comment: Why are you using Swift 2. Swift 3 is the future, and the longer you work with Swift 2 the harder your transition will be. (The syntax, and the mapping of Foundation class function names to Swift both changed quite a bit in Swift 3.)

Comment: Thank you Sulthan and Duncan C. I didn't know that NSData(contentsOfURL:) blocks the main thread. Is there a resource that outlines which calls block the main thread, as well as which calls automatically run on a background thread?  To answer what happens if I run my code for several minutes -- no problem there, everything eventually works.  To answer why I'm using Swift 2:  I am close to finishing a huge project that has taken well over a year, and I am months behind.  The amount of code I have is staggering, and I am concerned that modifying my code to Swift 3 will delay the launch too much.

Comment: Fahim, thanks but I can't share the full project.

Answer (score 0):

I am posting an answer not because I came up with the idea myself but because I want to provide readers actual code of what worked to solve my issue.

Based on the above advice, I am now converting NSData on a background thread, and within that block am updating my UILabel on the main thread.  Here's the code, starting just above the for loop:

```
    var itemNum = 1                     
    let qualityOfServiceClass = QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND
    let backgroundQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(qualityOfServiceClass, 0)
    for item in items {
        let jsonItem = JSON(item)
        let photoURLString = jsonItem["postingImageUrl"].stringValue
        let url = NSURL(string: photoURLString)
            dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, {

                if let imageData = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!) {
                    let photo = UIImage(data: imageData)
                    self.photosBeingDisplayed.append(photo!)                                
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                        self.progressLabel.text = String(itemNum) + " photos found"
                        itemNum++ // We increment itemNum here rather than in the main code of the for loop because these photos are getting processed on the background thread and we are not guaranteed they will finish in order.
                        })
                    }
              })
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This caused me a lot of problem. I hope this can be of use to future readers. The following worked for me when nothing didn't :

```
self.label.text = ....
[[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] runUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0.5]];
```

Answer (score -1):

Try updating `label` on `main thread` with `performSelectorOnMainThread` method.

Comment: I tried it, and in my selector function I put both a print statement as well as my code to set the text of the UILabel.  The print statement printed to the logs but the UILabel text still did not update.

Comment: One possible case for blocking main thread is gettting NSData from url. Try converting NSData from url in background and update label on main thread.

Comment: `dispatch_async` on the main queue and `performSelectorOnMainThread` makes no difference in practice.